# Database not update the value

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to make a social app .. and I want when the user clicks the edit category database should be updated to the new value .. but it is like static not changing to new value .. I don't know the problem in logic or in the code ..

```
    private void showCategoryUpdateDialog(String Key) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("تغيير " + Key);


    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setPadding(15, 10, 15, 10);

    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    radioButton.setText("علمي علوم");
    RadioButton radioButton2 = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    radioButton2.setText("علمي رياضة");
    RadioButton radioButton3 = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    radioButton3.setText("أدبي");

    linearLayout.addView(radioButton);
    linearLayout.addView(radioButton2);
    linearLayout.addView(radioButton3);

    builder.setView(linearLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String value = radioButton.getText().toString().trim();
            String value2 = radioButton2.getText().toString().trim();
            String value3 = radioButton3.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                pd.show();
                HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                result.put(Key, value);

                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(result)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter " + Key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value2)) {
                pd.show();
                HashMap<String, Object> result2 = new HashMap<>();
                result2.put(Key, value2);

                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(result2)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter " + Key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value3)) {
                pd.show();
                HashMap<String, Object> result3 = new HashMap<>();
                result3.put(Key, value3);

                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(result3)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter " + Key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    builder.create().show();

}
```

In this picture have more details

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfY2L.png)

And this GIF from my Database

[https://media.giphy.com/media/ZY36QuzJsdXIhIQh7k/giphy.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD6go.gif)

Comment: Hi, take a look at https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and try to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, this will make it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

first: make sure that the new value is stored in the database (from the console)
second: after the update is completed `onCompleteListener` get the data again.
you can listen for this field changes in real-time which could be better than getting the data after every update.